# How can I access a specific part of my volumes directory?

Tags: mac, virus

My antivirus software has told me that a potentially unwanted program called 'Bundlore'has been detected, but to remove it I need to do so manually. It says it's located in /Volumes/Install/Install.app/Contents/MacOS/monetizer 
I've gone into my volumes, but where exactly would I be able to find the software?

Answer (score 4):

When you open the 'Finder' application - in the sidebar there is probably an install disk that you can eject (has an eject icon next to the name).

You can also open the 'Terminal' program and type in `cd /Volumes/` and then `ls -la`. This gives you a listing of what is in that directory. If it's not in there, you have probably already ejected the install disk.

Also - I've looked at the 'Bundalore' program you describe and found a adware removal guide. This goes through every step of finding and removing it. [The Safe Mac: Bundlore](http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-bundlore/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`/Volumes/Install/Install.app` sounds like an application installer on a .dmg file that you downloaded and opened. If that's the case, you won't be able to delete it from there, as it'll be a read-only file. Just eject the 'Install' volume using the Finder sidebar, and it'll be gone.

If you hadn't yet run that application installer, then you probably don't need to worry about it any more.

If you *have* run it, then it's fairly safe to assume that it installed Bundlore on your Mac, along with whatever you were expecting it to install. In that case, follow the instructions that Sidney provided to fully remove it.